# Как получить значение функции лапласа? Python

Tags: python, статистика, scipy

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как получить значение функции Лапласа (функции стандартного нормального распределения) в python?

Функция `laplace.pdf()` из `scipy` дает не то значение. Значения не совпадают с табличными значениями интегральной функции Лапласа:

[image: laplace cdf plot]

Comment: Вы можете привести пример входных и ожидаемых данных ?

Comment: `>>> from scipy.stats import laplace` / `>>> laplace.pdf(0)` / `0.5` У меня всё как положено, что я делаю не так?

Comment: `for i in range(-20, 20): print('#' * int(laplace.pdf(i / 10.0) * 100))` — а вот такой код рисует график, который в точности совпадает с картинкой в википедии

Comment: @andreymal, у меня тоже...

Comment: Давайте сюда те табличные значения, которые вы ожидаете, а то у нас согласно википедии всё работает

Comment: http://matecos.ru/formuly/formuly-i-tablitsy/tablitsa-laplasa.html

Comment: Ну это явно не стандартное нормальное распределение :) Точнее, это что-то близкое к интегралу нормального распределения, если я правильно понял

Comment: Нарисовал график этой таблички, чтоб другим проще было https://i.imgur.com/FLQv7vZ.png ; а сам я таких функций не знаю

Comment: мда, на нормальное распределение это совсем не похоже

Comment: [похоже вы плотность распределения с самим распределением путаете (последнее этого интеграл первого)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9B%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0)

Answer (score 4):

Нашёл: значения упомянутой таблицы даёт функция `scipy.stats.norm.cdf(x) - 0.5`. Только вот по-моему к Лапласу она никакого отношение не имеет, ибо это интеграл от обычного гауссового распределения.

Comment: чего-то `scipy.stats.norm.cdf(np.linspace(0,1,101))` дает значения не совпадающие с "таблицей"...

Comment: @MaxU потому что 0.5 вычесть забыли

Comment: точно! торможжжжуууу... `scipy.stats.norm.cdf(np.linspace(0,1,101)) - 0.5` - возвращает как раз нужную таблицу

Comment: @ТолкачёвИван, по-моему это как раз то, что вы ищете...

Answer (score 2):

Гугль подсказывает, что math.erf(x)

Comment: И близко не то. По крайней мере в сравнении с таблицей (которая, похоже, просто названа неправильно)

Answer (score 1):

```
scipy.stats.norm.cdf(x)
```

Дает интеграл плотности распределения. По сути оно и есть функция Лапласа. Это интеграл от минус бесконечности до х. Оно же зовется cdf.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В таблицах используется нормированная функция Лапласа, которая (как уже отмечалось) равна обычной функции минус 0,5. Она представляет интеграл от 0 до х.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот вывод из книги Письменный Д.Т. Конспект лекций по теории вероятностей, математической статистике и случайным процессам:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Отсюда и понятно, почему нужно вычитать 0,5. Ведь интеграл всей плотности вероятности равен единице. А он симметричен. И именно отрицательная часть равна 0,5.

Так же вы можете использовать erf. Она связана с cdf (см [статью](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA) на википедии).

А [вот этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/457805/12993040) дал мне возможность ускорить cdf еще сильнее чем scipy.

В своем проекте я вешаю еще jit компиляцию. И это выходит в два раза быстрее чем `cdf.(Normal(0,1),x)` на Julia. В итоге ускорение в сравнении с scipy было в 10 раз.

Моя реализация представлена ниже. Но к сожалению у неё отсутствует проверка входных данных, так что обеспечьте её сами.

```
@nb.njit(cache=True)
def cdf(x):
    """
    Расчет функции Лапласа.

    Внимание! Отключена проверка по границам
    """

    x = x / 1.414213562
    a1 = 0.254829592
    a2 = -0.284496736
    a3 = 1.421413741
    a4 = -1.453152027
    a5 = 1.061405429
    p = 0.3275911
    s = np.sign(x)
    t = 1 / (1 + s * p * x)
    b = np.exp(-x * x)
    y = (s * s + s) / 2 - \
        s * (((((a5 * t + a4) * t) + a3) * t + a2) * t + a1) * t * b / 2
    return y
```